# selenium MicrosoftDriver

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I've just updated Windows to Windows 10, version 1709 today. And when I tried to start my Selenium WebDriver tests, the tests on Microsoft Edge failed. This is the exception that I get:

[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBMBf.png)

And the output says "Unable to connect to the remote server".

I think that the MicrosoftDriver is not compatible with the new version of Windows. Has anybody encountered this problem and fixed it or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're MicrosoftDriver doesn't work is because you're using the old version (15.15063.0). There's a new version on the microsoft website:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

This version is compatible with the new Windows update. Unfortunately this update still hasn't been uploaded in the NuGet Package Manager of Visual Studio.